# 3D vector constructor C++

Tags: c++, vector

For a 2d vector, I know I can go:

```
vector<vector<T>> vec;
vec = vector<vector<T>> (boardSize, vector<T>(boardSize));
```

But how do I do it for a 3d vector?

I tried

```
vector<vector<vector<T>>> vec;
vec = vector<vector<vector<T>>> (boardSize, boardSize, vector<T>(boardSize));
```

But it wouldn't compile. Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have a `vector<T>`, and make the size of it the product of all of the dimensions? Then wrap it in a class that converts multiple indices into a single index? It'd be a lot easier than what you're trying to do. Or just use Boost.MultiArray.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why isn't easy to use 3D vectors? I've been using 2D vectors without drama. Not arguing just interested, I'm fairly new to this. :)

Comment: Because there's no such thing as a "3D vector" or a "2D vector". They're just a vector that just so happens to contain another vector. The memory allocated by these objects is not contiguous. Plus, you have to resize each sub-vector manually. It's just a big hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess:

```
vec = vector<vector<vector<T>>> (boardSize, vector<vector<T>>(boardSize, vector<T>(boardSize)));
```

That means, when you've declared a `vector<vector<T>>`, the second argument should be a `vector<T>`; and when you declared a `vector<vector<vector<T>>>`, the second argument should be a `vector<vector<T>>`, which in turn should be as in the first case.

Comment: I think.. I think I love you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing would be not to do it. Create a class that offers the interface of a 3D vector (with [some changes](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10)) and internally use a single dimension vector.